# Why is Oracle PARTITION BY case insensitve?

Tags: oracle

We are using Oracle 19 Standard Edition under Amazon RDS.  It's decided that PARTITION BY should behave case INsensitively in certain sessions, whilst GROUP BY and everything else is still case sensitive.

For example, I have this test:

```
CREATE TABLE DLTEST
(
   NAME_VARIATION VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
   OTHER VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)
)
LOGGING;

INSERT INTO DLTEST (NAME_VARIATION, OTHER) VALUES ('Ostrich', 'A');
INSERT INTO DLTEST (NAME_VARIATION, OTHER) VALUES ('ostrich', 'B');
INSERT INTO DLTEST (NAME_VARIATION, OTHER) VALUES ('OSTRICH', 'C');
COMMIT;

SELECT NAME_VARIATION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME_VARIATION ORDER BY OTHER) AS RN
FROM   DLTEST
```

Results when run from SQLPlus in the US, or Toad in the UK (correct):

| NAME_VARIATION | RN |
| --- | --- |
| OSTRICH | 1 |
| Ostrich | 1 |
| ostrich | 1 |

Results when run from SQL Developer in the US (incorrect):

| NAME_VARIATION | RN |
| --- | --- |
| OSTRICH | 1 |
| Ostrich | 2 |
| ostrich | 3 |

The guy in the US has confirmed the following:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_SORT', 'NLS_COMP');
```

his results are:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_SORT | BINARY_CI |
| NLS_COMP | BINARY |

What could it be about his session which treats data case insensitively when running PARTITION BY?  If he does a GROUP BY, it works case sensitively.  Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The BINARY_CI in NLS_SORT means Case Insensitive!

In SQL Developer, he configured the preferences to skip NLS settings, and then it reports BINARY for both NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP, and the PARTITION BY works case sensitively again.